# How to block the reload of page on change image event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a form that contain several fields, one of these fields is a container that contain this:

```
<form id="formAddEvent" className="w3-container w3-cell" autoComplete="off" action="#" onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
    <div id="photoContainer" className="w3-container w3-cell w3-padding-16">
        <img id ="uploadedPhoto" className="uploadedPhoto" alt=""/>
        <img src={photo} id="logoPhoto" className="logoPhoto" alt=""/>
        <h6 id="loadPhotoText" className="loadPhotoText w3-center">Carica una foto</h6>
        <input type="file" className="inputPhoto" id="inputPhoto" name="photo" accept="image/*" onChange={this.imageSelectedHandler} />
    </div>
</form>
```

The method `imageSelectHandler` do this:

```
imageSelectedHandler = (event) =>{
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("uploadedPhoto").src=path+event.target.files[0].name;
    document.getElementById("logoPhoto").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("loadPhotoText").style.display="none";
}
```

And the submit method is:

```
submitHandler = (event) =>{
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

My problem is that sometimes, when I change image, the current page reload.
How can avoid this behaviour?
Thank you in advance.

---

### Edit

This is the entire code:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import { withAlert } from "react-alert";
import Period from "./Period";
import { Provider } from "react-alert";
import AlertTemplate from "react-alert-template-basic";
import axios from "axios";
import ConfirmUpdate from "./ConfirmUpdate";
import ConfirmAddEvent from "./ConfirmAddEvent";
import ConfirmDraft from "./ConfirmDraft";
import Topic from "./Topic";
import close from "./../../image/close.png";
import photo from "./../../image/photo.png";
import add from "./../../image/plus.png";
import "./../../stylesheet/AddEventForm.css";




var path = "/eventImage/";


class AddEventForm extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            topics: [],
            addPeriodIsClicked: false,
            periodsList: [],
            showConfirmUpdate: false,
            showConfirmAddEvent: false,
            showConfirmDraft: false
        }   
        this.removeTopicFromArray = this.removeTopicFromArray.bind(this); 
        this.updateAddPeriodIsClicked = this.updateAddPeriodIsClicked.bind(this);
        this.appendResult=this.appendResult.bind(this);
        this.updateEventHandler = this.updateEventHandler.bind(this);
        this.addEventHandler = this.addEventHandler.bind(this);
        this.draftEventHandler = this.draftEventHandler.bind(this);
    }

submitHandler = (event) =>{
    event.prevetDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
}

onCloseHandler = () =>{
    this.props.updateAddEventIsClicked();
}


imageSelectedHandler = (event) =>{
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    document.getElementById("uploadedPhoto").src=path+event.target.files[0].name;
    document.getElementById("logoPhoto").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("loadPhotoText").style.display="none";
    return false;
}

removeTopicFromArray = (topic) =>{
    var array = [...this.state.topics];
    var index = -1;

    for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        if(topic.props.topicName === array[i]){
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    array.splice(index,1);
    this.setState({
        topics: array
    });
}

addTopicContainerHandler = () =>{
    var arrJSON = localStorage.getItem("arr");
    var arr = JSON.parse(arrJSON);
    var topicName = (document.getElementById("inputTopic")).value;
    var firstInstanceInLocalStorage = true;
    var firstInstance = true;

    for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){  //verifico se esiste una copia del topicName tra quelle già memorizzate, in caso contrario la memorizzo
        if(topicName.toUpperCase() === arr[i].toUpperCase()){
            firstInstanceInLocalStorage = false;
        }
    }

    if(firstInstanceInLocalStorage){
        arr.push(topicName);
        var objectJSON = JSON.stringify(arr);
        localStorage.setItem("arr",objectJSON);
    }

    for(let i=0; i<this.state.topics.length; i++){ //verifico se esiste una copia del topicName tra quelle già inserite, in caso contrario la inserisco
        firstInstance = true;
        if(this.state.topics[i].toUpperCase() === topicName.toUpperCase()){
            firstInstance = false;
            break;
        }       
    }

    if(firstInstance){
        this.setState({
            topics: [...this.state.topics,  topicName]
        });
        axios.post("http://localhost:8080/topicEvents",topicName).then(topicEvents=>{
        console.log(topicEvents.data)
        })
    }


    (document.getElementById("inputTopic")).value = "";
}

updateAddPeriodIsClicked = () =>{
    this.setState({
        addPeriodIsClicked: !this.state.addPeriodIsClicked
    });
}

appendResult = (periods) =>{
    this.setState({
        periodsList: []
    });
    console.log(periods)
    var periodsList= [];

    for(let i=0; i< periods.length; i++){
        periodsList.push(periods[i]);
    }

    this.setState({
        periodsList: periodsList
    });

    var length = periodsList.length/4;
    var div;
    var att;
    var period;
    var dateListContainer = document.getElementById("dateListContainer");

    while(dateListContainer.childElementCount !== 0){
        dateListContainer.removeChild(dateListContainer.firstChild);
    }

    for(let i=0; i<length; i++){
        period = "Dal "+ (periodsList[0 + (i*4)]) + " Al "+ (periodsList[1 + (i*4)]) + " - Dalle ore "+ (periodsList[2 + (i*4)]) + " Alle ore "+ (periodsList[3 + (i*4)]);
        div = document.createElement("DIV");
        att = document.createAttribute("class");
        att.value="w3-container";
        div.setAttributeNode(att);
        div.innerHTML = "<h6>"+period+"</h6>";

        dateListContainer.appendChild(div);
    }

        if(this.state.addPeriodIsClicked){
            this.updateAddPeriodIsClicked();
        }
}

buttonHandler = (event) =>{
    var inputPhoto = document.getElementById("uploadedPhoto").src;
    var eventName = document.getElementById("eventName").value;
    var periodLength = this.state.periodsList.length;
    var detailsBox = document.getElementById("detailsBox").value;
    var topicsLength = this.state.topics.length;


    if((inputPhoto!=="")&&(eventName!=="")&&(periodLength!==0)&&(detailsBox!=="")&&(topicsLength!==0)){
        if(this.props.eventInfoIndex!==-1){
            if(event.target.getAttribute("id")==="update"){
                this.updateConfirmUpdate();
            } else {
                this.props.updateAddEventIsClicked();
            }
        } else {
            if(event.target.getAttribute("id")==="draft"){
                this.updateConfirmDraft();
            } else {
                this.updateConfirmAddEvent();
            }
        }
    } else {
        this.props.alert.error("Campi incompleti");
    }
}

addEventHandler(){
    var inputPhoto = document.getElementById("uploadedPhoto").src;
    var eventName = document.getElementById("eventName").value;
    var detailsBox = document.getElementById("detailsBox").value;
    var array = localStorage.getItem("eventsArray");
    var eventsArray = JSON.parse(array);
    var isDraft = false;

    var id = eventsArray[eventsArray.length-1].id+1;
    var newEvent = {
        id: id,
        name: eventName,
        photo: inputPhoto,
        periods: this.state.periodsList,
        description: detailsBox,
        topic: this.state.topics,
        isDraft: isDraft,
        isMapped: false
    }

    axios.post("http://localhost:8080/events",newEvent).then(events=>{
        console.log(events.data)
    })

    eventsArray.push(newEvent);
    localStorage.setItem("eventsArray",JSON.stringify(eventsArray));

    this.props.updateSomethingIsChange();
    this.props.updateAddEventIsClicked();
}

draftEventHandler(){
    var inputPhoto = document.getElementById("uploadedPhoto").src;
    var eventName = document.getElementById("eventName").value;
    var detailsBox = document.getElementById("detailsBox").value;
    var array = localStorage.getItem("eventsArray");
    var eventsArray = JSON.parse(array);
    var isDraft = true;

    var id = eventsArray[eventsArray.length-1].id+1;
    var newEvent = {
        id: id,
        name: eventName,
        photo: inputPhoto,
        periods: this.state.periodsList,
        description: detailsBox,
        topic: this.state.topics,
        isDraft: isDraft,
        isMapped: false
    }

    axios.post("http://localhost:8080/events",newEvent).then(events=>{
        console.log(events.data)
    })

    eventsArray.push(newEvent);
    localStorage.setItem("eventsArray",JSON.stringify(eventsArray));

    this.props.updateSomethingIsChange();
    this.props.updateAddEventIsClicked();
}

updateEventHandler(){
    var inputPhoto = document.getElementById("uploadedPhoto").src;
    var eventName = document.getElementById("eventName").value;
    var detailsBox = document.getElementById("detailsBox").value;
    var array = localStorage.getItem("eventsArray");
    var eventsArray = JSON.parse(array);

    eventsArray[this.props.eventInfoIndex].photo = inputPhoto;
    eventsArray[this.props.eventInfoIndex].name = eventName;
    eventsArray[this.props.eventInfoIndex].periods = this.state.periodsList;
    eventsArray[this.props.eventInfoIndex].description = detailsBox;
    eventsArray[this.props.eventInfoIndex].topic = this.state.topics;

    var update = {
        name: eventName,
        photo: inputPhoto,
        periods: this.state.periodsList,
        description: detailsBox,
        topic: this.state.topics,
        isDraft: eventsArray[this.props.eventInfoIndex].isDraft,
        isMapped: eventsArray[this.props.eventInfoIndex].isMapped
    }

    axios.put("http://localhost:8080/events/"+eventsArray[this.props.eventInfoIndex].id,update).then(events=>{
        console.log(events.data)
    })
    localStorage.setItem("eventsArray",JSON.stringify(eventsArray));

    this.props.updateSomethingIsChange();
    this.props.updateAddEventIsClicked();
}



updateConfirmAddEvent = () =>{
    this.setState({
        showConfirmAddEvent: !this.state.showConfirmAddEvent
    })
}

updateConfirmDraft = () =>{
    this.setState({
        showConfirmDraft: !this.state.showConfirmDraft
    })
}

updateConfirmUpdate = () =>{
    this.setState({
        showConfirmUpdate: !this.state.showConfirmUpdate
    })
}

autoComplete = () => {
    var arrJSON = localStorage.getItem("arr");
    var arr = JSON.parse(arrJSON);
    var inp = document.getElementById("inputTopic");
    inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
        var a, b, i, val = this.value;
        closeAllLists();
        if (!val) { 
            return false;
        }
        a = document.createElement("DIV");
        a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
        a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items w3-container");          
        this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() === val.toUpperCase()) {
                b = document.createElement("DIV");
                b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
                b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
                b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
                b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                    inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                    closeAllLists();
                });
                a.appendChild(b);
            }
        }
    });

    function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (elmnt !== x[i] && elmnt !== inp) {
                x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    closeAllLists(e.target);
    });
} 

componentDidMount(){
    var events = localStorage.getItem("eventsArray");
    var eventsArray = JSON.parse(events);
    var index = this.props.eventInfoIndex;

    if(index !== -1){ //vuol dire che addEventForm è stato chiamato da un evento e non dal pulsante del menu
        document.getElementById("uploadedPhoto").src=eventsArray[index].photo;
        document.getElementById("logoPhoto").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("loadPhotoText").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("eventName").value = eventsArray[index].name;
        document.getElementById("detailsBox").value = eventsArray[index].description;

        this.setState({
            periodsList: eventsArray[index].periods,
            topics: eventsArray[index].topic,
        });

        this.appendResult(eventsArray[index].periods);
    }
}


render(){
    return(
        <div id="addEventWrapper" className="modalAddEvent">
            <div id="modal" className="w3-modal">
                <div className="w3-modal-content w3-card-4 w3-animate-zoom">

                    <form id="formAddEvent" className="w3-container w3-cell" autoComplete="off" action="#" onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                        <div id="photoNameEventContainer" className="w3-panel">
                            <div id="infoTitleContainer" className="w3-container">
                                <h2 id="infoTitle">Informazioni di base</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div id="photoEventContainer" className="w3-panel w3-cell-row">
                                <div id="labelPhotoContainer" className="w3-container w3-cell w3-left-align">
                                    <h6 id="labelPhoto">Foto dell'evento</h6>
                                </div>
                                <div id="photoContainer" className="w3-container w3-cell w3-padding-16">
                                    <img id ="uploadedPhoto" className="uploadedPhoto" alt=""/>
                                    <img src={photo} alt="" id="logoPhoto" className="logoPhoto" />
                                    <h6 id="loadPhotoText" className="loadPhotoText w3-center">Carica una foto</h6>
                                    <input type="file" className="inputPhoto" id="inputPhoto" name="photo" accept="image/*" onChange={this.imageSelectedHandler} />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="nameEventContainer" className="w3-panel w3-cell-row">
                                <div id="labelNameContainer" className="w3-container w3-cell w3-left-align">
                                    <h6 id="labelName">Nome dell'evento</h6>
                                </div>
                                <div id="inputNameContainer" className="w3-container w3-cell w3-padding-16">
                                    <input type="text" id="eventName" className="w3-input" name="eventName"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="dateContainer" className="w3-panel">
                            <button onClick={this.updateAddPeriodIsClicked}>Scegli una o più date</button>
                        </div>

                        <div id="dateListContainer" className="w3-panel"/>

                        <div id="detailsContainer" className="w3-panel">
                            <div id="detailsTitleContainer" className="w3-container">
                                <h2 id="detailsTitle">Dettagli</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div id="descriptionContainer" className="w3-container w3-cell-row">
                                <div id="labelDescriptionContainer" className="w3-container w3-cell w3-left-align">
                                    <h6 id="labelDescription">Aggiungi una descrizione</h6>
                                </div>
                                <div id="boxDescriptionContainer" className="w3-container w3-cell">
                                    <textarea id="detailsBox" name="description"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="topicContainer" className="w3-panel w3-cell-row">
                            <div id="labelTopicContainer" className="w3-container w3-cell w3-left-align">
                                <h6 id="labelTopic">Aggiungi un Topic</h6>
                            </div>
                            <div id="inputTopicContainer" className="w3-container w3-cell">
                                <input type="text" id="inputTopic" className="w3-input" name="inputTopic" onInput={this.autoComplete}/>
                            </div>
                            <div id="addBtnContainer" className="w3-container w3-cell">
                                <img src={add} alt="+" className="addBtn" onClick={this.addTopicContainerHandler}/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div id="topicListContainer" className="w3-panel">
                            {this.state.topics.map(topic =>(
                                <Topic key={topic} id={topic} topicName={topic} removeTopicFromArray={this.removeTopicFromArray}/>
                            ))}
                        </div>
                        {   (this.props.eventInfoIndex===-1) &&
                            <div id="buttonContainer" className="w3-panel w3-cell-row">
                                <div id="draftContainer" className="w3-container w3-cell">
                                    <button id="draft" onClick={this.buttonHandler}>Salva come bozza</button>
                                </div>
                                <div id="publishContainer" className="w3-container w3-cell">
                                    <button id="publish" onClick={this.buttonHandler}>Pubblica</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                        {   (this.props.eventInfoIndex!==-1) &&
                            <div id="buttonContainer" className="w3-panel w3-cell-row">
                                <div id="draftContainer" className="w3-container w3-cell">
                                    <button id="undo" onClick={this.buttonHandler}>Annulla</button>
                                </div>
                                <div id="publishContainer" className="w3-container w3-cell">
                                    <button id="update" onClick={this.buttonHandler}>Apporta le modifiche</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </form>

                    <div className="closeBtnContainer w3-cell"> 
                        <img src={close} alt="x" onClick={this.onCloseHandler} className="cancelBtn"/>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="periodContainer">
                {   this.state.addPeriodIsClicked &&
                    <Provider template={AlertTemplate} {...{position: "bottom center",  offset: "100px", transition: "scale", timeout: 5000}}>
                        <Period updateAddPeriodIsClicked={this.updateAddPeriodIsClicked} appendResult={this.appendResult} periodsList={this.state.periodsList}/>
                    </Provider>
                }
            </div>
            {this.state.showConfirmUpdate && 
                <ConfirmUpdate 
                    updateConfirmUpdate={this.updateConfirmUpdate}
                    updateEventHandler={this.updateEventHandler}
                    eventName={this.props.eventName}/>}
            {this.state.showConfirmAddEvent && 
                <ConfirmAddEvent 
                    updateConfirmAddEvent={this.updateConfirmAddEvent}
                    addEventHandler={this.addEventHandler}/>}
            {this.state.showConfirmDraft && 
                <ConfirmDraft 
                    updateConfirmDraft={this.updateConfirmDraft}
                    draftEventHandler={this.draftEventHandler}/>}
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default withAlert(AddEventForm);
```

Comment: Have you tried to add `return false` at the end of both of your functions?

Comment: Yes, but the behaviour is the same

Comment: have you tried with event.stopPropagation() ?

Comment: Yes, but doesn't work

Comment: Are these examples the real codes or do you somehow upload your image somewhere else?

Comment: I have omitted only the superfluous code

Comment: There are other fields that contains information like event name, periods ecc. but I've think that they are unnecessary for my problem

Comment: Omitting is no problem, I just wonder do you upload those images to a backend and do you use hot reloading?

Comment: What do you mean with "hot reloading"?

Comment: I mean hot reloading with `react-hot-reloader` directly or by using CRA. Still, I couldn't get an answer to my question about uploading images. Nevermind. I just want to say, if you are uploading those images to a backend in your project directory, hot reloading causes refreshes.

Comment: So, you are posting these images with somewhere with your form right?

Comment: I post these images through the input field and take them from a public directory

Comment: Are you posting/uploading/saving those images again in your project directory? @M.Morris, my question is a simple one :)

Comment: No, I don't. My images are present only in public directory

Comment: Can you tell me which is the last executed line before the page is redirected?

Comment: I'm doing some test for localize the last executed line, I'm noted that when the page reload in the console I can see this message info "The development server has disconnected.
Refresh the page if necessary". Could be a problem relative to the server and not to the code?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to `return false;` from your submitHandler function and `event.stopPropagation();` to prevent further propagation of the submit event.

```
submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I've just tried too and that work pretty well. So, have you got a system of hot reloading instead of Hot Module Replacement ? Or can you give us your entire code please ?

Comment: OP is insisting on not giving enough information :) @M.Morris, please provide as much info as you can.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion